# LAG ON GAMES AND MOUSE POINTER Ubuntu 16.10

Tags: nvidia, mouse

im using Ubuntu 16.10 and from two days i have "micro lag" with mouse pointer (I tried other distros like Arch Linux and i got the same problem)
On games like CS GO months ago i got the same performance of Windows, now i have continuosly micro freeze like the mouse...
I have a GTX 950 nvidia with propietary driver (nvidia-367),help me please.